# Asynchronous components and WinForms 

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, tcpclient

I'm currently writing a component to communicate with an Ethernet based device and am having to use asynchronous sockets. At times when I receive specific 'commands' from the device, I need to raise an event for whatever program is using my component (most usually a WinForm.) I'm creating a sample form for the user but I am having difficulty allowing the client form to receive the events and modify the form; I'm getting the typical "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listStrings' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I've tried reading over [Implementing the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a34yad.aspx), and [Walkthrough: Implementing a Component That Supports the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz33kx67%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), though it doesn't quite seem to be exactly what I need, especially when reading "Opportunities for Implementing the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern" in the first link.

.Net / C# is more of a hobby than profession, and in this project - this is the last piece I need to figure out before being able to complete it. Would it be better to use a "thread-safe" (I know, everyone throws that term around like it only means one thing) existing TCP/IP component rather than trying to implement it myself?

EDIT: Here's my network class code to show you how I'm implementing it now. I forget where I came across this snippet, but it's worked fine up until I've added the form.

```
internal class Network
{
    private Device dev;
    private TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream ns;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    private Queue<byte[]> _msgQ = new Queue<byte[]>();

    public Network(Device d)
    {
        dev = d;
    }

    internal void Connect(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        client.BeginConnect(ipAddress, port, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
    }

    internal byte[] getLocalIp()
    {
        return ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address.GetAddressBytes();
    }

    private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            ns = new NetworkStream(client.Client);
            ns.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 2048, new AsyncCallback(OnRead), null);
            while (_msgQ.Count > 0)
            {
                byte[] message = _msgQ.Dequeue();
                ns.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            }
            dev.dvDevice._connected = true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    internal void Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            client.Close();
            dev.dvDevice._connected = false;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    internal void Write(byte[] message)
    {
        if ((!client.Connected) || ns == null)
        {
            _msgQ.Enqueue(message);
            return;
        }
        ns.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
    }

    private void OnWrite(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            ns.EndWrite(ar);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void OnRead(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int recv = ns.EndRead(ar);
            byte[] message = new byte[recv];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, message, 0, recv);
            dev.dvDevice._mh.Parse(message);
            ns.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 2048, new AsyncCallback(OnRead), null);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

`Device` is the class which is exposed to the client. It contains a `MessageHandler` (_mh) class which does all the parsing. `Device` contains the public event which is called by the `MessageHandler` on specific responses. Hopefully this helps in what I have so far; I'd prefer not having to rewrite too much, but to make it right (and work properly), I will if I must.

EDIT (2):
My goal for this library is that the user should not at all have to manage any of the threads - so when an event is raised, say "ReceiveString", the user should just be able to act on it without any thought.

EDIT (3):
More code for completeness.

```
public delegate void OnStringEvent(byte[] str);

public class Device
{
    internal struct _device
    {
        // other stuff too, but here's what's important
        public bool _connected;
        public bool _online;
        public MessageHandler _mh;
        public Network _net;
    }

    public event  OnStringEvent OnString;

    internal void ReceiveString(byte[] str)
    {            
        OnString(str);
    }

    internal _device dvDevice;
    public Device(int device_number, int system_number)
    {
        dvDevice = new _device(device_number, system_number);
        dvDevice._mh = new MessageHandler(this);
        dvDevice._net = new Network(this);
    }
}

internal class MessageHandler
{
    private Device dev;

    public MessageHandler(Device d)
    {
        dev = d;
    }

    public void Parse(byte[] message)
    {
        // The code goes through the message and does what it needs to
        // and determines what to do next - sometimes write back or something else

        // Eventually if it receives a specific command, it will do this:
        dev.ReceiveString(ParseMessage(ref _reader));
     }
}
```

Comment: is that the only error you get? Well the only problem then is that you're accessing UI (any controls or the form) from your other threads.

Comment: you aren't touching `listStrings` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @gideon - `listStrings` is a listbox in the form. The raised event, in this case "ReceiveString", adds the received string into the listbox.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is raising the event? Most likely from the device class if I understand you correctly.

Comment: You should consider capturing the `SynchronizationContext` from the GUI thread Nd having your callbacks perform their operations through that.

Comment: Casper - this is GOLDEN! After reading up on what `SynchronizationContext` was and figuring how to implement it, I fixed all of my code within a matter of minutes. I'm not entirely sure of the proper etiquette, but if you provide an answer with this, I'd mark that as accepted.

Since my `Device` class is created on the GUI thread, I was very easily able to pass the context from that class into my `MessageHandler`, which in turn raised the event needed. You definitely saved the day! I do appreciate everyone's response, they were all very helpful in that I've learned something from each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @Polity's answer, being an Rx fan I would say use Rx (Reactive Extensions)

```
 //we convert a typical begin/end (IAsyncPattern) into an observable sequence
 //it returns a Func -read() that takes a byte, two ints and returns one.
 var read = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[], int, int, int>
                            (networkStream.BeginRead, networkStream.EndRead)
.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher);

// Now, you can get an IObservable instead of an IAsyncResult when calling it.
byte[] someBytes = new byte[10];
IObservable<int> observable = read(someBytes, 0, 10);

observable.Subscribe(x=> 
//x will be the returned int. You can touch UI from here.
);
```

---

Based on your code I can see that another thread calls the `OnString` event, then I **assume** when you subcribe to it, you're just adding the string into the listbox.

```
device.OnString += new OnStringEvent(device_onstring);

void device_onstring(byte[] str)
{ 
 listStrings.Items.Add(...);//this is wrong, will give cross thread op error.
 //you do this: 
 this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
   {
       listStrings.Items.Add(..);
       //or anything else that touches UI
   });
 // this should refer to a form or control.
}
```

Comment: At first glance, this appears that it would fit well into my existing code. Can you explain the three ints involved?

Comment: @jjames This statement (`<byte[], int, int,int>` ) represents the [NetworkStream.BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx) without the `IAysnCallBack` and `object`. So its more like the plain [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) method. It takes three params and returns one. When you call `FromAyncPattern` like this, it returns a `Func` of the type you specified that will do all the dirty work for you returns an observable, which is like a sequence of events.

Comment: So - short of rewriting / rethinking how I handle everything in the component, the user will be forced to add this bit of code? I may be in over my head.

I can't compile it - but I'll work it out.

Comment: @jjames Updated a typo in my second snippet. It is the shortest way you can fix things.

Comment: Aha - thanks! This'll work for now until I rewrite the entire thing - which I tend to do often . . . learning experience. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome! Seems like if your code is being consumed, a rewrite wouldn't be so bad, with Rx/TPL you can rally make your code elegant to use and learn something fun! =D

Answer (score 2):

Do youself a favor and rely on TPL to do the synchronization lifting for you. Example:

```
NetworkStream stream = MySocket.NetworkStream;

// creat a Task<int> returning the number of bytes read based on the Async patterned Begin- and EndRead methods of the Stream
Task<int> task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
        fs.BeginRead, fs.EndRead, data, 0, data.Length, null);

// Add the continuation, which returns a Task<string>. 
return task.ContinueWith((task) =>
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        ExceptionTextBox.Text = task.Exception.Message;
    }
    else 
    {
        ResultTextBox.Text = string.Format("Read {0} bytes into data", task.Result);
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: This assumes the initial call was on the GUI thread; as long as that's always the case, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in 2 places depending on your design.  If the event is raised from a different thread you can handle it in the event handler by checking the .invokeReqeuired property of the form( or other control) handling the event.  If it returns true you should use the .beginInvoke method to marshal the call to the proper thread.

Depending on your design you can handle it from the other end by passing your component an instance of the form you want to marshal to.  Before you raise the event, check .invokeRequired and marshal the call so that the event is raised in the proper thread.  This way the code using your library doesn't have to worry about threads, but it required that your library have a reference to system.windows.forms.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a pretty easy problem to solve: you just need to execute any code in your form that updates controls using Invoke.

The precise implementation will depend on how the async code is calling back into your form. If you add that code to your question, we can provide a more complete answer.